# Final attributes inside ViewHolder class?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-viewholder

I have just generated a `Master/Detail Flow` project, and I find something strange: inside `DriverListActivity.java`, the subclass called `ViewHolder` has `final` attributes. Since the data inside `ViewHolder` is probably to be replaced, 
why the attributes are set as `final`??

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View mView; //???????
    public final TextView mIdView; //???????
    public final TextView mContentView; //???????
    public DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
        mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Final doesn't mean the objects can't be mutated.  Final means the references themselves can't be replaced.  You can still call mIdView.setText() on a final reference.

Think of it like in C.  There's a pointer (a reference) and a value.  Final means the pointer is unchangable, not the value it points to.  And  ViewHolder will not change the values of the views inside of it once created-  that's the reason we use the ViewHolder pattern-  those references are constant.

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` is going to create limited amount of particular `ViewHolder`. Having, for example 100 similar items in your data set does **not** mean, that you are going to have 100 `ViewHolder`s created. You're going to have roughly that much `ViewHolder`s, that are needed in order to fill in the screen viewport, say 10 items.

Now, as soon as you scroll, the `ViewHolder` of the first item, that is going out of the screen would be recycled and given back to `onBindViewHolder()` in order to setup the view for the item, that is going to come to the screen from the bottom (assuming we have a vertical `RecyclerView`).

Within `onBindViewHolder()` all you are going to do is mutating the field according to your needs, e.g.:

```
holder.titleTextView.setText(dataSet.get(position));
```

See here, no need to change the reference of `holder.titleTextView`, only mutation happens, thus it can easily be declared as `final`.

Answer (score 0):

> the final keyword is used in several different contexts to define an
>   entity that can only be assigned once.
>
> Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same
>   value. If a final variable holds a reference to an object, then the
>   state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but
>   the variable will always refer to the same object (this property of
>   final is called non-transitivity). This applies also to arrays,
>   because arrays are objects; if a final variable holds a reference to
>   an array, then the components of the array may be changed by
>   operations on the array, but the variable will always refer to the
>   same array.